# Webapp2 Create an index page for a subset of Handlers

Tags: python, webapp2

I am in the process of writing some js unit tests (using qunit) for my python webapp2 application, and I wish to create an index page of all of my unit test suites.  Each unit test suite is mapped to a single url and to a single handler object.  Each of these handler objects inherits from a common base class TestHandler.  Here is the handler to url mapping.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/test',
        handler=TestHandler,
        name='testindex'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/test/datastream', 
        handler=TestStreamHandler, 
        name='datastream'),
    webapp2.Route(r'/test/timecontrol', 
        handler=TestTimeControlHandler, 
        name='timecontrol'),
], config=webapp2_config)
```

Is there a way to automatically read what test urls are available, and then generate an index html page containing links to all of the unit test suite pages?

Comment: This answer wil help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078892/in-webapp2-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-route-uris